# Why can not use static readonly object property?

Tags: c#, initialization, uri

This is constants class:

```
 public static class Constants
    {
        public const string USER_ID = "conduent";
        public const string PASSWORD = "593becd1-02f6-46f0-bf34-25b393ad041b";
        public static readonly Uri BASE_URI = new Uri("https://staging.test-476b.com");
        public static readonly Uri GET_TOKEN_URI = new Uri("api/session");
        public static readonly Uri SEND_CASE_URI = new Uri("api/referral_request");
    }
```

And this is usage

```
public class DanestreetHttp
    {

        private AuthToken authToken = null;

        private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = Constants.BASE_URI
        };
}
```

On the screen shot you can see the error, that was disappeared after I have changed `BaseAddress = Constants.BASE_URI` to `BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://staging.test-476b.com")`. What is wrong with static readonly initialiazation?

Screen

[image: Image 2]

PS. My current solution: `BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseAddress)`

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error messages (something to read: [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)). If you have an error, explain the error in your question, including the full error message. Oh, before doing that, read the error message yourself and try to understand it. Most likely it will tell you what is wrong which should hopefully give you an idea of how to fix the error.

Comment: Does image 1 show anything image 2 does not?

Comment: @HimBromBeere actually, you are right, I' going to delete the first

Comment: It was because you are trying to set string type to BaseAddress type

Comment: @elgonzo The screen is provided to proove that  `Constants.BASE_URI` has been succefully created

Comment: @MilanRaval Where have I tried this?

Comment: @Nikita: Sorry, I read it wrong. But the error is about format of uri could not be determined, and not anything related to static read only object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 2 or the URIs are invalid in `Constants`, preventing this class to initialize property. It should work if you replace

```
public static readonly Uri GET_TOKEN_URI = new Uri("api/session");
public static readonly Uri SEND_CASE_URI = new Uri("api/referral_request");
```

with

```
public static readonly Uri GET_TOKEN_URI = new Uri("http://api/session");
public static readonly Uri SEND_CASE_URI = new Uri("http://api/referral_request");
```

(or https)

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O9AFOm)